# Deploy production and UAT web services at once

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, testing, jboss, wildfly

I have a web service that runs on Wildfly on `http://localhost:8080/ws` which I deploy from maven using wildfly-maven-plugin.

I would like to deploy the same web service, but pointing to a test datasource, to `http://localhost:8080/ws_test` so I can use it as a UAT enviroment and run tests without affecting the production database.

Is there an easy way to do that?

---

More information:

- The root (`ws`) is configured in `jboss-web.xml`:

  ```
  <jboss-web>
    <context-root>/ws</context-root>
  </jboss-web>
  ```
- I have this class:

  ```
  @ApplicationPath("/")
  public class MyApplication extends Application { }
  ```
- my production datasource is "hardcoded":

  ```
  @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/jdbc/prod")
  private javax.sql.DataSource ds;
  ```
- the maven pom (extract):

  ```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <hostname>localhost</hostname>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>pass</password>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this:

- add a second datasource corresponding to the test DB:

  ```
  @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/jdbc/test")
  private javax.sql.DataSource dsTest;
  ```
- let my controller know it could be called from two URIs:

  ```
  @Path("{a:(test/)?}some_page")
  public class MyController { ... }
  ```
- direct the calls to the right DB:

  ```
  private @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

  DataSource getDatasource() {
    LOG.info("in mode: {}", uriInfo.getPath());
    return uriInfo.getPath().startsWith("/test") ? dsTest : ds;
  }
  ```